# Using out << in Grails taglib

Tags: grails, groovy

In a Grails taglib I have seen:

```
out << 'some html'
```

and I've also seen:

```
out << body() << 'some html'
```

What is the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first outputs the string to the response. The second renders the body of the tag to the response and then also renders the string. Not all tags have a body, so the 2nd one is more rare. For example `<g:img src='foo.gif'/>` doesn't have a body but `<g:ifLoggedIn>Welcome Back</g:ifLoggedIn>` does.

When you define a tag closure, it either has one argument, typically 'attrs', or two, typically 'attrs' and 'body'. The names don't matter, they're just sensible defaults. The `body` argument will be a closure that renders the inner content of the tag when it's invoked like a method (i.e. `body()`)